# SP to update 3rd table using data in first 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

For e.g. I have below table1 and table3. The 'Counts' field in table2 should be updated based on valuess field in table1 and table3. i.e. 23 appears 4 times in table1 and table3 and 45 appears once. Table2 should be updated with that count.

table1

```
Id | Data | Valuess 
1  | rfsd | 23
2  | fghf | 45
3  | rhhh | 23
```

table3

```
Id | Data | Valuess 
1  | rfsd | 23
2  | tfgy | 23
```

table2

```
Id | Fields | Counts
1  | 23     |   4 
2  | 45     |   1
```

I am using the below stored procedure to achieve this.

```
WITH t13 AS (
SELECT Id, Data, Valuess FROM Table1 UNION ALL SELECT Id, Data, Valuess FROM Table3), 
cte AS (SELECT Valuess,COUNT(*) AS Count2 FROM t13 GROUP BY Valuess)

UPDATE t2
SET t2.Counts = cte.Count2
FROM Table2 t2 JOIN cte ON t2.Fields = cte.Valuess;
```

QUESTION

Now instead of above table data, i have below table data....

table1

```
Id | Data | Valuess 
1  | rfsd | 004561
2  | fghf | 0045614
3  | rhhh | adcwyx
```

table3

```
Id | Data | Valuess 
1  | rfsd | 0045614
2  | tfgy | 004561
```

table2

```
Id | Fields  | Counts
1  | 0045614 |   4 
2  | adcwyxv |   1
```

So here we have alphanumeric data in valuess field of table1 and table3. Also we have data like '004561' and '0045614'

I want to clip off the 7th element of the field and compare it with clipping off 7th element in the table 3. i.e. 004561, 004561 and adcwyx will be taken from table1. 004561 and 004561 will be taken from table3 and compared with 004561 and adcwyx of table2 ( we need to clip off 7th element in table2 first) and then compare.

The final result should be as shown in table2.

Comment: SQL-Server != MySQL.

Comment: How does `adcwyx` as a value in table1 become `adcwyxv` in table2?

Comment: sqlzim- it is 2 different data values and not depended on each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUBSTRING` should do it.

```
WITH t13 AS (
  SELECT Id, Data, SUBSTRING(Valuess,1,6) AS [Values] 
    FROM Table1 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT Id, Data, SUBSTRING(Valuess,1,6) AS [Values] 
  FROM Table3
  )
, cte AS (
  SELECT [Values],COUNT(*) AS Count2 
  FROM t13 GROUP BY [Values]
  )
UPDATE t2
SET t2.Counts = cte.Count2
FROM Table2 t2 JOIN cte ON SUBSTRING(t2.Fields,1,6) = cte.[Values];
```